# norms on vector space are equivalent iff they have same topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Note that (1) all norms on finite dimensional vector space are equivalent.

And here (2) norms on vector space are equivalent iff they have same topology.

Question : How can we prove (2) ? Please recommend reference

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: think in the identity
$$I:(E,\|\cdot\|_1)\longrightarrow(E,\|\cdot\|_2)$$
and in the zero-centered balls in both norms.

Comment: This is for finite dimensional case ?

Comment: @HKLee, is for the question in the title.

Comment: I read statement (1) and (2) So in infinite dimensional vector space we has nonequivalent two norms. $\|\ \|_2$ cannot be a metric on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Comment: @HKLee, I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: @HKLee, $\Bbb R^\omega$ is the set of eventually zero sequences or the set of all sequences? And what is your $\|\cdot\|_2$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is set of all sequence and $\| x\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i^2 } $

Comment: @HKLee, $\|\|_2$ isn't norm because $\|(1,1,1,1,\cdots)\|_2 = \infty$

Comment: @HKLee, and my $\|\|_1,\|\|_2$ are arbitrary norms.